# Why this error handling in a separate function is giving error?

Tags: parsing, rust

I am trying to convert a string to a float in a standalone function:

```
use std::error::Error;
pub fn my_str2float(ss: &str) -> Result<f64, dyn Error> {
    let n = ss.parse::<f64>()?; 
    Ok(n)
}

fn main (){
    let numstr = "12.33"; 
    
    match my_str2float(numstr) {
        Ok(num) => { println!("Number read: {}", num); }
        Err(e) => { println!("Error while reading number: {}", e.to_string()); }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:4:40
  |
4 | pub fn my_str2float(contents: &str) -> Result<f64, dyn Error> {
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)`
note: required by a bound in `Result`
 --> /rustc/9eb3afe9ebe9c7d2b84b71002d44f4a0edac95e0/library/core/src/result.rs:503:1

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `testfns` due to previous error
```

How can I get known size at compile time?
Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are facing is that [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html) (`dyn Error` in your case) are dynamically sized:

> Due to the opaqueness of which concrete type the value is of, trait objects are [dynamically sized types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html). Like all DSTs, trait objects are used behind some type of pointer; for example `&dyn SomeTrait` or `Box<dyn SomeTrait>`.

##### Solution 1: Using a `Box<dyn Error>` instead of `dyn Error`

Wrapping your `dyn Error` in a `Box` will work just fine:

```
use std::error::Error;

pub fn my_str2float(ss: &str) -> Result<f64, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let n = ss.parse::<f64>()?; 
    Ok(n)
}

fn main (){
    let numstr = "12.33"; 
    
    match my_str2float(numstr) {
        Ok(num) => { println!("Number read: {}", num); }
        Err(e) => { println!("Error while reading number: {}", e.to_string()); }
    }
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe20f50168b9c072ffd7baba4753ec29)

##### Solution 2: Replace `dyn Error` with a concrete error type

You don't have to return a trait object as error, you can also use a concrete error type. In your case that'd be [`ParseFloatError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.ParseFloatError.html), as this is the error returned by `ss.parse::<f64>()`:

```
use std::num::ParseFloatError;

pub fn my_str2float(ss: &str) -> Result<f64, ParseFloatError> {
    let n = ss.parse::<f64>()?; 
    Ok(n)
}

fn main (){
    let numstr = "12.33"; 
    
    match my_str2float(numstr) {
        Ok(num) => { println!("Number read: {}", num); }
        Err(e) => { println!("Error while reading number: {}", e.to_string()); }
    }
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=01a92b3cc7ac1e9398ec62b2fd34ff0e)

##### Solution 3: Using `impl Error`

Unlike `dyn Trait`, [`impl Trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/impl-trait.html#abstract-return-types) in return position also returns a concrete, sized type. The caveat (compared to returning a concrete type directly) is that you can only use the methods of the trait. It also requires us to give the compiler more type hints than the other two solutions:

```
use std::num::ParseFloatError;
use std::error::Error;

pub fn my_str2float(ss: &str) -> Result<f64, impl Error> {
    let n = ss.parse::<f64>()?; 
    Ok::<f64, ParseFloatError>(n)
}

fn main (){
    let numstr = "12.33"; 
    
    match my_str2float(numstr) {
        Ok(num) => { println!("Number read: {}", num); }
        Err(e) => { println!("Error while reading number: {}", e.to_string()); }
    }
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=599f460a153af558af66aa86adc3d059)

---

Thanks to @Jmb for pointing out options 2 and 3.

Comment: Or use `impl Error` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=939ad015aafbda1f89d1dd034145b499)) or an explicit error type (here `std::num::ParseFloatError`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=eea9369f539a8bc10f277b2a6e0e5ee3))

Comment: Good points @Jmb , you should write these  as full answers.